# Is it ethical to attend a company-organised event after my last day?

Tags: ethics, resignation, quitting

My company co-organises lots of events and if the events are of technical nature, we as employees, get promo codes that allow us free entry. One such event is being organised in a couple of weeks. What is different this time is that I put in my notice and I will be leaving the company. My last day is a couple of days before the event. The code was given out recently and I am planning to use it to enter it.

How unethical would that be considered? I am leaving on good terms with everybody. I am taking a month off so I won't be employed yet when the conference takes place.

Comment: @KillianDS No idea, and I wouldn't even know how to check it. Since we just get the code in email, I assume all the employees are granted free entry and it's up to the company to enforce a rule to limit it to the employees?

Comment: If you wanted to be totally ethical you could ask HR (or whoever gave you the code) if you must return it before you leave the company. If the answer is no, go for it.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if you've found yourself asking anonymous strangers on the Internet for approval of an action you intend to take that benefits yourself, you're probably on the wrong side of the ethics of it.

Comment: "My last day is a couple of days before the event."  So if you worked one more day, and then attended the event (on company time), you would still be an employee.  Why not just avoid the questionable situation by working just one more day?  Since you mentioned taking a month off, it seems you may be available.  If you have PTO (vacation) day saved up, you might not even need to work it.

Comment: It's amazing that a question caused by me being completely absent-minded and not thinking about the most obvious options is so popular. :-)

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The ethical thing to do is ask your company if it's OK to use the code to attend even though you will have finished up there by that time. And then abide by their answer on the matter.

Comment: Nobody ever thinks of that angle, now do they?

Comment: @RichardU It's easy to rationalise your way around things when you don't get what you want. But a reputation that people can rely on your rock steady ethics is a big asset in the long haul. Don't waste it on little things.

Comment: You can get a lot of mileage on your ethics.  When I was laid off for one position, I took the high road, sent out a thank-you email, behaved above-board right up through my last day.  Five years later, I got a project from the same company.  Your reputation is everything.  I agree, it's a huge asset.

Comment: so much answers that could be rewritten as "use your common sense"

Comment: @ithil Common sense is a subjective sense. What seems common sense for you might be "thinking out of the box" for others. That's why we have laws.

Comment: @ithil common sense, by definition, is defined by usage. Usage is communicated by the people. This site is the medium for that communication. These answers represent common sense.

Comment: @RichardU: But the Workplace SE would go extinct if people just talked with each other to figure things out! (Academia SE too)

Comment: I upvoted this post solely because it's the only StackExchange post to have more upvotes than characters: https://data.stackexchange.com/workplace/query/575247

Comment: @barrycarter not even close look at this one http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/79416/boss-sends-a-birthday-message-how-to-reply/79417#79417

Comment: @Kilisi Oh wow, that was the post I was looking at that led me to this post. So you're saying the results of the linked query are wrong or that I'm reading them wrong?

Comment: @barrycarter they must be wrong or out of date I guess?

Answer (score 6):

If this was a *social* event, I think the "ethics" issue would be "well, why not?" So far as you and your former colleagues were concerned, it would be more or less an extension of any "leaving party" that you might (or might not) organize yourself. In the past I've even been *invited* by a former employer to social events (in the evening) organized for visiting customers whom I had worked with for a long time.

But the OP describes this as "technical" and a "conference". If such an event is not "open to the general public," quite likely you will be hearing some confidential information about the company's future plans, etc. Ethically, I think that's a good reason why you should *not* be there at all - or at least, you should not be there without having been given formal *permission* to attend.

Comment: I don't see where they say it is not open to the public - my reading is that it is a public dev meetup that the company sponsors, and gets free entry for it's employees.

Comment: @Jac The OP doesn't say whether or not any member of the public can attend. It's not clear to me what "co-organizes" and "of a technical nature" means here. I think the basic ethical point is the OP is *not* an employee when the event actually happens - he/she might have accepted a job offer from a direct competitor, who would otherwise be excluded from it. It is possible the OP would not have been given access to the event even if he/she *was* still an employee, but had given notice of leaving the company.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you avoid using quotation marks around phrases and words that do not appear in the text you are referring to, as it makes it appear that you are quoting the text when you are not. Instead of "don't do this because x must be true!", try saying things like "if the event is likely to present confidential information that you should not have access to, then you shouldn't go" and then your answer isn't filled with speculative assumptions.

Comment: Well, after several decades working regularly with people from the US, I'm quite used to their desire to teach us Brits how to speak and write our own language. Do Americans know the phrase "water off a duck's back"?

Comment: Dunno, I'm British.

Comment: Unnecessary quotation marks are equally popular (and equally wrong) on both sides of the Atlantic.  As for ducks, a lot more water runs off their backs in Britain, but that may be weather-related.

Comment: There's no confidential information involved. Anyone with fifty bucks in their pocket can attend.